# How to prevent variables from being used when a file is include() ed

Tags: php, scope, php-include

The title is a little confusing, I know. Basically I want to prevent a variable in one file which I include() into another file form being used. 
Example:

File1.php:

```
<?php
$foo = "Bar";
?>
```

File2.php:

```
<?php
include("File1.php");
echo $foo;
?>
```

In the above example File2.php will obviously echo "Bar"; however, I want to prevent this from happening while still being able to access any functions inside File1.php. Ideally variables declared outside of functions should not be accessible when the file is included() ed.

Comment: `unset($foo);` but really this screams poor code structure.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other choice than to use this type of code structure.

Comment: @nogd this is the correct answer, please post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php):

File1.php:

```
<?php
namespace baz {
    function foo() {
        return "Bar";
    }
}
namespace { // global code
    $x = "XXX";
}
?>
```

File2.php:

```
<?php
include("File1.php");
echo $x; // outputs XXX
echo foo(); // Undefined
?>
```

To access `foo` you have to use [use](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

File2.php:

```
<?php
include("File1.php");
use function baz\foo;
echo foo(); // outputs Bar
?>
```

Comment: Will this still allow functions in the namespace to be called (Im new to using namespaces)?

Comment: @HittmanA updated my answer. You can read more on the links that I have posted.

Comment: @Rex Weber maybe I didn't clarify. If I dont use use (confusing, again I know) will I still be able to call functions without allowing access to variables?

Comment: Yes. You have to put your functions on the global scope/global namespace, and put your variables in a different namespace.

Comment: Ok and can variables in one namespace (in the same file) interacts with other variables (or functions) in another namespace (in the same file, again)

Comment: Yes, using `use`. :)

Comment: ;P Should have know. Ok thanks again. You have been a huge help!